# Ruby Block: Storing the result of each line of a proc into a variable?

Tags: ruby, eval, block, proc

I was wondering if someone (like myself =]) could create some method to do something like this:

```
x = magic_method do
  create_string "some_string" # a method that returns "This is <some string>\n "
  create_string "other_string"
  create_string "third_string"
end
```

Which would then return

```
puts x #=> This is some_string\n This is other_string\n This is third_string
```

Answer (score 0):

Several options.  The simplest would be to just mutate the original string:

```
def create_string(str)
  str.sub!(/\A/, "This is ") << "\n"
end
```

Comment: The part that confuses me there is: how are each of the strings concatenated? I would expect the result of this block just to return the last string. Could you elaborate on how this would work?

Comment: If you read the documentation for `#sub!` (http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-sub-21) and `<<`, you'll see that it actually modifies the `str` variable, so in addition to returning the result, the original string has been changed before it is passed to the next method.

Comment: I fully understood that part; What I don't understand is how each line is concatenated:
create_string "some_string" will certainly return "this is some_string\n", but in no way will it affect create_string "other_string"; this will not append this to the string resulting from the first method call. 

One way that I suspect I can achieve this effect is to pass the block to a string: "".instance_eval(&block), where each method modifies the self object. I'm seeing if there are other ideas other than this.

Comment: Keep in mind that the point of the task is to return a concatenation of all of the method calls inside of a block that is passed to a function, not to simply modify a string. Then the method will do something with this string. If I'm missing something, please let me know.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. That's not possible in ruby.